# Escape \ in XML?

Tags: c#, xml, escaping

In C# code, I've used the below format for Date Time in `.ToString()` method.

```
Format= "\"'\"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff\"'\""
```

this format also appends quotes to the formatted date time in string and works well when used in csharp.

However, I want to pass this format in an XML file but serialization fails because of `\`.

How to escape `\"'\"` in format ?

Answer (score 2):

**Backslash** (`\`) **is *not* an escape prefix character in XML:**

- `\` itself does not ***need*** to be escaped in XML [character data](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-chardata).
- `\` itself is not ***allowed*** to appear in XML component (element or attribute) [names](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameChar).

**To escape**:

- `&` use `&amp;`
- `"` use `&quot;`
- `'` use `&apos;`
- `<` use `&lt;`
- `>` use `&gt;`

But be sure to take context into account: [***XML character escaping requirements are context sensitive***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46637835/290085).